# attempting multiple activites via button click

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I am writing an app that will display a menu of juices at a vape shop.
I have the main screen which displays the name and a button that once clicked will send the user to a new screen displaying the menu.
I am having trouble setting up the button click and when i run the app it crashes after the button is clicked

any input would be appreciated!

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.vitoriano_vaz.easybayvapes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(FromActivity.this, ToActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void startJuiceMenu(View view) {
        Log.d("MyApp", "button clicked");


    }
}
```

**Second activity once the button is clicked**

```
package com.example.vitoriano_vaz.easybayvapes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class juiceMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> juiceMenu = new ArrayList<String>(50);

    private static String VALUE = "myValue";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        juiceMenu.add("#1 Blueberry Bombshell");
        juiceMenu.add("#2 Richie Rich");
        juiceMenu.add("#3 Chiquita");
        juiceMenu.add("#4 Afternoon Delight");
        juiceMenu.add("#5 Poppin Otters");
        juiceMenu.add("#6 Viva La Sangria");
        juiceMenu.add("#7 Okole Maluna");
        juiceMenu.add("#8 Carmen Miranda");
        juiceMenu.add("#9 Pomalade");
        juiceMenu.add("#10 Izual");
        juiceMenu.add("#11 Butter Stotch ");
        juiceMenu.add("#12 Blue Bulls");
        juiceMenu.add("#13 Grape Ape");
        juiceMenu.add("#14 Bruce Juice");
        juiceMenu.add("#15 Doc Holiday");
        juiceMenu.add("#16 Peachy Keen");
        juiceMenu.add("#17 Hula");
        juiceMenu.add("#18 New York");
        juiceMenu.add("#19 Al Gore");
        juiceMenu.add("#20 Lux Charms");
        juiceMenu.add("#21 Sailor jack");
        juiceMenu.add("#22 Get Him to the Greek");
        juiceMenu.add("#23 Key We Lie Chi");
        juiceMenu.add("#24 Spring Fling");
        juiceMenu.add("#25 Gumby");
        juiceMenu.add("#26 Chai-Milk");
        juiceMenu.add("#27 Mr. Bean");
        juiceMenu.add("#28 50 Shades of Orange");
        juiceMenu.add("#29 Blue Waffles");
        juiceMenu.add("#30 Enigma");
        juiceMenu.add("#31 Mr. Freeze");
        //juiceMenu.add("#32 New Flavor"); need to update to get newest flavor



  }


}
```

**Activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.vitoriano_vaz.easybayvapes.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/main_view">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Welcome to East Bay Vapes"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/juicemenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/JuiceMenu"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity_juice_menu**
here i have a LinearLayout for the ArrayList I declared in juicemenu.java class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.vitoriano_vaz.easybayvapes.juiceMenu">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/JuiceMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >

    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vitoriano_vaz.easybayvapes">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".juiceMenu"></activity>
    </application>

</
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Intent` that you are building needs to reference your own `Activity` classes.
The first parameter is a `Context` and the second is the `Class` of the `Activity` you want to start so it should be the following.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, juiceMenu.class);
```

Comment: thank you it ended up working!
now i just need to populate my activity_juice_menu.xml with the data in my ArrayList

Comment: Great. I was about to add a comment that you also need a call to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_juice_menu`) in `juiceMenu.onCreate()` so it knows which layout to display but it looks sounds like you might have noticed that already.

Comment: so once i add the setContentView call to my activity_juice_menu, how would i go about populating the second activity in a List format

Answer (score 0):

Since your question has already been answered, I thought I'd suggest a more efficient means of populating your array to remove that blemish from your code.  For example you can use a string-array resource.  With that you simply add the values using a single code line.  As an example:

> String[] juiceArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.JuiceTextArray);

The array values themselves are populated in your arrays.xml file (found in values folder) as such:

```
<resources 
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
   tools:ignore="MissingTranslation"> 

    <string-array name="JuiceTextArray" tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">
        <item name="Juice1">#1 Blueberry Bombshell.</item>
        <item name="Juice2">#2 Richie Rich.</item>
        [etc., etc.]
   </string-array>
</resources>
```